# Undeclared identifier error

Tags: c, opencv, pthreads, face-detection

I wrote this code for face detection on a thread, then I will write for eyes, nose, and mouth.

But there is a mistake which is --- `'threadface_func' : undeclared identifier` ---

I can't find what it is.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "cv.h"
    #include "highgui.h"
    #include <pthread.h>

    typedef struct parameter_t{
        CvSeq * detectRect_face;
        IplImage* capturedImg;
        CvHaarClassifierCascade * pCascade_face;
        CvMemStorage * storage;


    }parameter_t;

    int main ( int argc, const char* argv[] )
    {
            CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
            IplImage* capturedImg;
            int resCount = 1;
            char path[50];
            int flags = CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH;

            CvHaarClassifierCascade * pCascade_face;
            pthread_t threadface;


            pCascade_face = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *)cvLoad("C:/Users/Furkan/Desktop/Computer Vision/Programlar/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
            cvNamedWindow("FaceDetection");

            while (true)
            {
                CvMemStorage * storage;
                CvSeq * detectRect_face;
                capturedImg = cvQueryFrame(capture);
                storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

                parameter_t my_parameters;

                int k=pthread_create(&threadface,0,threadface_func,(void*)&my_parameters);

                if(k!=0)
                {
                    printf("Create thread failed! error");
                    return 1;
                }


                cvShowImage("FaceDetection", capturedImg);

                int ch = cvWaitKey(1);

                if(ch==27)
                    break;
                else 
                    if(ch == 115)
                    {
                        sprintf(path,"d:/resim%d.bmp",resCount++);
                        cvSaveImage(path,capturedImg,0);
                    }
            }

        cvDestroyWindow("FaceDetection");

        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

        return 0;
    }


    void* threadface_func(void* parameter){


        parameter_t *p =(parameter_t*)parameter;

        p->detectRect_face=cvHaarDetectObjects(p->capturedImg,p->pCascade_face,p->storage,1.15, 3, 0,cvSize(25, 15));

        for(int i=0;i<(p->detectRect_face ? p->detectRect_face->total:0); i++ )
            {
                CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(p->detectRect_face, i); 
                CvPoint pt1 = { r->x, r->y }; 
                CvPoint pt2 = { r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height }; 
                cvRectangle(p->capturedImg, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1,8, 0); 

            }

        return 0;
    }
```

Please help...

Comment: Post the complete error message

Comment: Probably not directly related, but could be a problem soon. It seems that you are compiling C++ code as C code. Don't do that, these are different languages and have subtle differences. In C, IO is done with the functions provided by the "`stdio.h`" header. `iostream` is C++.

Answer (score 3):

In C, functions have to be declared ahead of where they are referenced. You reference the function `threadface_func` in the middle of `main()`, so you have to declare it somewhere before that.

The simple fix is to add this just above `main()`:

```
void* threadface_func(void* parameter);
```

Alternatively, you could move the whole function before `main()`.

Comment: I did your solution. Thank you. it is solved. But now There is another error which is ---unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create referenced in function _main--- ???

Comment: @FrknErgt - when building with pthread you need to link to the pthread library